# Deferred and ajax and queuing functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I am implementing a queue system of various information. When it reaches a certain number, I send an ajax request.... user inputs data, when it reaches certain point I send it. BUT, the user can still be entering data. I don't want to lose that.. so, I was thinking of I could use a `$.Deferred/promise`, while storing the data to a certain point.. firing ajax, and only allow a new request when the previous deferred is successful... also, if the data being entered then increased to the point I have to send it again, I que it..

I am having a hard time wrapping my brain around the methodology of how to implement.

===> capture data

=======> 'n' amount of data is entered

=============> move that data into the 'ready' bucket. (arbitrary, lets user entered 10 input fields and I store into an array. when array reaches 10.. boom send it ).

=============> fire ajax with the 10 items

In the meantime the user can still be entering data. I want to make sure I still capture it and keep que'ing and sending at 10.

I was thinking of a queuing system with a deferred. Not sure if I am over thinking this.

Comment: Your approach seems fine... what's your question?

Comment: I am not fully versed in Deferred's enough to implement them w/o careful thought. I was looking for a way in which I would implement the above. If I just programmed it, sure done in a jiffy - but I think I would lose out on some power deferreds bring. But, again, I am not well versed in them - been reading up on them. Hard to grasp.

Answer (score 3):

Since the jqXHR object returned by `$.ajax()` is a Promise, that can be used.

```
var data = {
    // captured data goes here
};

function sendData( val ){
    // jqXHR object (which contains a promise)
    return $.ajax('/foo/', {
        data: { value: val },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( resp ){
            // do whatever needed
        }
    });
}

function when(){
    $.when(sendData(data)).done(function (resp) {
        when();
    });
}

when(); // use this within the if switch
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/brAWk/)

Comment: Thank you! Still waiting on better rep so I can upvote etc.. those that help. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user1492442 I've corrected an error, and added demo link. Glad this helped

Comment: code-jaff -- how would you implement something that Roamer did below in that you have a batchSize.

Comment: Why not just `sendData(data).then(when)` ? Or better yet, drop `.when` altogether and implement a promise repeater

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your queue is the array `dataQueue`, then you can do something like this :

```
var dataQueue = [];//sacrificial queue of items to be sent in batches via AJAX request
var batchSize = 10;
var requesting = false;//flag used to suppress further requests while a request is still being serviced

//addToQueue: a function called whenever an item is to be added to he queue.
function addToQueue(item) {
    dataQueue.push(item);
    send();//(conditional on queue length and no request currently being serviced)
}

function send() {
    if(dataQueue.length >= batchSize && !requesting) {//is the queue long enough for a batch to be sent, and is no ajax request being serviced
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/server/side/script',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataQueue.splice(0, batchSize)),//.splice removes items from the queue (fifo)
            ... //further ajax options
        }).done(handleResponse).fail(handleFailure).always(resetSend);
        requesting = true;
    }
}

function handleResponse(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //handle the server's response data here
}
function handleFailure(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //handle failure here
}
function resetSend() {
    requesting = false;//Lower the flag, to allow another batch to go whenever the queue is long enough.
    send();//Call send again here in case the queue is already long enough for another batch.
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LA68w/)**

Notes:

- There's no particular reason to return the jqXHR (or anything else) from `send` but by all means do so if your application would benefit.
- `resetSend` needs not necessarily be called as the `.always` handler. Calling from the `.done` handler (and not the `.error` handler) would have the effect of "die on failure".
- To minimise the number of members in your namespace (global or whatever), you might choose to encapsulate the whole thing in a contructor function or singleton namespace pattern , both of which are pretty trivial.
- Encapsulating in a constructor, would allow you to have two or more queues with the desired behaviour, each with its own settings.
- The demo has a few extra lines of code to make the process observable.
- In the demo, you can set the batchsize to 15, add-add-add to get the queue length up to, say, 12, then reduce the batchsize to 5 and add another item. You should see two sequential requests, and 3 residual items in the queue.

Comment: I have a question - lets say the que reached its limit (batchsize) of 10 again before the prior send() is complete. Then it won't fire again until another item is moved into que to then reinitialize it all over again. right? That is why I was thinking a deferred queing so that whenever it is finished, the 'next in line' que'ing would fire and not be left out if the prior call takes longer than the que the fills to its batch size.

Comment: The code in the answer already has this feature. A latent queue (length less that batchsize) will only respond to the addition of another item. However, a queue that is already being serviced will continue to be serviced, in batches, until its length is less than batchsize. To see this in action, follow the procedure in my last note (revised).